# Failover Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, high-availability, failover, redundancy

I am looking to setup my Nginx reverse proxy to handle a server failure or Nginx failing for some reason or another. I know how to configure nginx to work as a load balancer/ reverse proxy for other servers but I didn't find any good guides on how to make Nginx redundant. Would it be as simple as having two servers and configuring my router to port forward to both?

Comment: If you're using AWS / Azure / similar it's best to use a managed load balancer. Otherwise you could look at [DNS load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/dns-load-balancing/), which isn't as good or as reliable but often works. You don't forward packets from your router to both Nginx instances, that sounds like duplicating traffic which isn't good.

Comment: @Tim VMware does not support that. My question does not apply to the cloud but instead on prem. This is for a personal setup so again DNS load balancing will not work for it. I have one public IP to work with which comes to a router which then needs to go to nginx in some HA option.

Comment: Your router is a single point of failure. One IP behind a consumer router, you don't have many options. I can't think of any right now.

Comment: @Tim Yes single router and single IP are points of failure, I am well aware. That doesn't mean I can't try to minimize the other single points of failure. My IP and router have never gone down other than when I planned them to. My Nginx reverse proxy on the other hand has gone down a few times and I want to avoid that happening again. Also my router is not a consumer one, it is a Cisco one just like my switches are Cisco too and servers are Dell. Only thing that is consumer in my whole stack is the modem.

Comment: Nginx is usually very reliable, so I'd look into why it failed. You could put HAProxy in front of Nginx and load balance to two Nginx instances on different ports, or Nginx / Apache on different ports. I don't know if HAProxy is any more reliable than Nginx. Can you edit your question to provide a basic overview of your setup? Router(s), servers, software running on the servers, the question could use a bit more detail. I'm starting to think maybe VMWare features might be worth investigating.